# Laravel Breeze API returns Laravel version with status code (200 Ok) when the log in credentials are not correct

Tags: laravel, authentication, breeze, credentials

I want to change the login logic in the Laravel Breeze. How do I make it to show up a message indicating false credentials when the login fails. Now, it returns Laravel version with status code 200.
I tried to look up the authenticate method but did not notice something useful.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.